# where to change text for header?

Tags: theme-customizer, custom-header

on the twentyfifteen theme. When I click on the customizer to set my header, There is some text there that says. "While you can crop images to your liking after clicking Add new image, your theme recommends a header size of 954 × 1300 pixels." I need to change the 954 x 1300 but I can't find where it is being generated from. I have tried various filters but nothing has worked.

How can I change those dimensions in the text?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `twentyfifteen_custom_header_args` filter for customizing width and height. Check following example.

```
add_filter( 'twentyfifteen_custom_header_args', 'theme_slug_custom_header_args' );
function theme_slug_custom_header_args( $args ){
  $args['width']  = 600;
  $args['height'] = 800;
  return $args;
}
```

In the example, width is changed to 600 and height is set to 800.

Comment: I was editing the wrong file. When you change the dimensions in custom-header.php which is located in the inc folder, it changes automatically. In my question. I wanted to change the text not the actual dimensions of the image.